# How can I fix this function which is supposed to work like a stopwatch?

Tags: javascript, delay

In this version of my code the timer instantly jumps to 30 seconds.

```
timer();

function timer() {

  while (end == 0 && sec<30) {
    milsec++;
      if (milsec==100) {
        sec++;
        milsec = 0;
      }
      setTimeout(timer(), 10);
  }

}
```

I tried many things before. I got the error call stack size exceeded, many times the whole page just stopped loading. Now I have come to a point where the whole thing works at least halfway, but the delay of 10 milliseconds is not working. Probably there is a simple solution to this problem but I just coudn't figure it out...

Comment: `setTimeout(timer, 10);` but that is not going to make any difference since that while loop is wrong. It is going to jump because the while loop is just going to keep running.

Comment: You have two loops going round. The SetTimeout and also the while.

Comment: not to mention `end`, `sec`, and `milsec` are not defined in what you're showing of course.

Comment: Also don't call the `timer()` function before it's defined. You're calling it in the setTimeout function

Comment: @MikeAbeln that part is, surprisingly, just fine. Functions get hoisted.

Comment: your variables are not declared and you seem to believe that the [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified) method works like a clock; which is technically impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember to read up on functions, because `setTimeout` schedules some code to run *at least* as many milliseconds into the future as indicated, but *only at least* that many milliseconds into the future. The only guarantee it makes it that your code will *not* run for that many milliseconds, but it says *nothing* about when it'll actually run. Could be 10ms, could be 2 minutes. Both are correct bahaviour.

So you can't use it as a clock, or as a stable counter for the passage of time. If you want that, you'll need to actually use the clock, i.e. `Date.now()` or `performance.now()`.

Thankfully, writing a stopwatch doesn't need an interval counter: all you care about is "the time when the user clicked start", and "the time the user clicked stop". Showing "a time spinner" isn't remotely required for those two events to do what we need them to do, it's just eye candy, so don't do more work than is necessary to make something that *looks* like a number spinner.

Pick an interval that is just about meaningful to humans, like 123ms (not 10, that's *way* too fast) and then schedule an interval (rather than a timeout: we don't care if there's interval drift or hitches etc, the page update just needs to happen "fast enough". Beyond that, we don't care). Every time that interval triggers, you check "how much time has passed since we started" by looking at the current time, and subtracting the start time, then you update the page with that value.

Don't increment anything during your interval, you already have all the information you need to show the passage of time.

And crucially: by doing things this way *it doesn't matter what interval we update at* because the only real times that matter are the start and stop times, the page update is purely cosmetic and has nothing to do with the actual time we're interested in. In fact, even if the page update *never happens*, our stop watch will still be correct because we're checking the *real* times only when the user clicks our button:

```js
let startTime = 0;
let timer = undefined;

const text = document.querySelector(`span`);
const btn = document.querySelector(`button`)
btn.addEventListener(`click`, toggle);

function toggle() {
  if (startTime === 0) start();
  else stop();
}

function start() {
  // take note of the current time
  startTime = Date.now();
  // and start our "eye candy" page update at an interval that's
  // low enough to "look like a number spinner" without running
  // more than a purely cosmetic update needs to run.
  timer = setInterval(updatePage, 123);
  btn.textContent = `stop`;
}

function stop() {
  // let's see for how long we were running:
  console.log(`stopwatch ran for ${Date.now() - startTime}ms`);
  // then clear our time variable
  startTime = 0;
  // and stop our page update timer. Always remember to stop your timers.
  clearInterval(timer);
  btn.textContent = `start`;
}

function updatePage() {
  // how many seconds have passed since the user pressed start?
  const timePassed = ((Date.now() - startTime)/1000).toFixed(3);
  // cool, cool: update the page with that number
  text.textContent = `${timePassed}s`;
}
```

```html
<span>0.000s</span> <button>start</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you can implement a stopwatch, using `Date.now()` to get the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since the UNIX epoch. You can use the difference between that number and the current time, and compare that against the `durationSecs` to get the remaining time. Once there's no time remaining, stop looping. This uses `requestAnimationFrame` to call the function approximately once every time the screen refreshes (so ~60 times per second on a standard 60 Hz monitor) because I don't think there's a reason to do it more often than that (especially for updating an element, which will only actually be updated once per refresh anyways). This isn't a recursive call in the sense that it will overflow the call stack, but it's technically recursive in the fact that it calls itself, but calling yourself inside of a `requestAnimationFrame` is a standard way to do updates once every frame.

```js
const timerElement = document.querySelector("#timer");
timer(30);

function timer(durationSecs, startingTimeMs) {
  startingTimeMs ??= Date.now(); // set the startingTimeMs if it's not defined
  const currentTimeMs = Date.now();
  const remainingMs = Math.max(durationSecs - (currentTimeMs - startingTimeMs) / 1000, 0);
  console.log(`Time remaining: ${remainingMs.toFixed(3)}`);
  timerElement.innerText = `Time remaining: ${remainingMs.toFixed(3)}`;
  if (remainingMs > 0) {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => timer(durationSecs, startingTimeMs));
  }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 20% !important; }
```

```html
<h1 id="timer"></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some things to clarify about your code.

- At this line of code `setTimeout(timer(), 10);` you wanted to tell the browser that the  `timer` function should be called back in 10 milliseconds, but, when you added parentheses after the function name, you did instead call it. To fix that, you should write `setTimeout(timer, 10);` (you pass the function name, do not run it), but that still will not fix your code;
- It says call stack exceeded because you called timer function (see the previous line) from itself. You did a recursive function, without a stop condition.
- Some variables are not defined (`end`, `sec` and  `milsec`). I don't know if you ommited these values;
- Doing a while loop to wait for something in JavaScript, that's a bad idea. Instead, you should do it in an [event-driven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) way. You should instead, at the end of your `timer` function, tell the browser you need it to be called back;
- setTimeout delay could be longer than intended (as already pointed out by [Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans answer in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76674765/2102777)). See the setTimeout function reference at Mozilla Developer Network Web Docs, for example.

If you simply want to fix your code, you could rewrite it like this:

```js
//First, declare the variables "sec" and "milsec" before using them.
var sec = 0;
var milsec = 0;

function timer() {
   milsec++;
   if (milsec == 100) {
       sec++;
       milsec = 0;
   }
   if (sec < 30)
       setTimeout(timer, 10);
   else {
       //Do your page update code here.
   }
}

timer()
```

But, for a full stopwatch code and a more detailed explanation, check [Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76674765/2102777).